# Possible to use UIActionSheet from Application Delegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, ios

I have a common `UIActionSheet` which I use across about 10 different view/view controllers. I'm wondering if it's possible to use `UIActionSheet` from the app delegate in order to prevent code duplication?

So far my attempts to use an action sheet from the delegate haven't worked, I suspect my problem lies when calling the `showInView` method - do I need to instantiate an object of my view controller then use `viewController.view` here? If so how can I then tell which view called the action sheet method from the delegate?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't try the approach proposed by c_phlat, but I wonder to what self.view is mapped.
I did manage to do it like this:

```
[actionSheet showInView:window];
```

it works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and I recently figured out a way to fix it in my app. The key for me was to make my app delegate class an extension of UIViewController rather than NSObject. (I think UIViewController is a subclass of NSObject anyway, so this shouldn't affect your app too much.)

In other words, change the main implementation line in your app delegate interface file from something like this:

```
@interface YourAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate> {
```

To this:

```
@interface YourAppDelegate : UIViewController <UIApplicationDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate> {
```

You should now be able to use the showInView: method with your action sheet within your app delegate implementation:

```
[yourActionSheet showInView:self.view];
```